# swap implementations: efficiency & range of applicability?

Tags: c++, function, implementation, effective-c++

I'm trying to cover all `swap`function implementations.

In the following implementations of the `swap` function there is no need of temporary variable to interchange the values of the two parameters:

```
void swapNoTemp1(int &a, int &b){
    a = a + b;
    b = a - b;
    a = a - b; 
}
```

or

```
template <class T>
void swapNoTemp2(T& i, T& j){
    i -= j;
    j += i;  
    i = (j - i);  
}
```

or

```
void swapNoTemp3(int &a, int &b){
    a ^= b;
    b ^= a;
    a ^= b;
}
```

thus making it more effective, in terms of used memory, than:

```
void swap(int &a, int &b){
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp; 
}
```

On the other hand, `swap` could be implemented using:

```
void swapPointers(int *i, int *j) {
    int t = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = t;
}
```

I'am trying to compare all existing implementations and understand their range of applicability.

Comment: Not really, no. Now you've outlawed a good number of input pairs.

Comment: Note also that it doesn't even work for `unsigned` (where there is no overflow), when `&a == &b`.

Comment: Rewrite is using XOR to avoid overflow.  A nice big comment would not hurt either.

Comment: Even if the function avoiding a temporary worked perfectly, the absolute best you could hope for is to save a `sizeof(int)` allocation on the stack. I very much doubt that would ever be worth worrying about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of the first function is undefined. The arithmetics may lead to overflow, and on some machines, overflows lead to exceptions.

The standard states:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of
>   representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined. [ *Note*: most existing implementations of C++
>   ignore integer overflows. ... ]

Although in practice you have good chances that the function will work, it is perhaps better to avoid it.

Comment: This is the correct answer, since OP used a signed integer type. It is perhaps worth noting that apart from hardware exceptions, there are many other ways to be bitten by this sort of undefined behavior (as the FreeBSD guys [recently were](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2015-February/054320.html)), and that unlike in the signed case, over- and underflow are well-defined for unsigned integer types by [basic.fundamental]/4.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis, If you need to check, overflowing in your check is not a good idea. Especially since no result you get could be greater than `INT_MAX` if it was defined to overflow (it isn't, as said above). The chosen undefined behaviour alternative to that just makes everything unpredictable.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis If `a` and `b` are `int`s, then `a+b` is `int` too. So (even if addition works) ithe sum is not expected to exceed `INT_MAX` :-).

Comment: If `a == INT_MAX` and `b == INT_MAX`, then `a + b` is not in the range of representable values for `int`, and the behavior is undefined as per [expr]/4 (which is quoted in the answer).

Comment: @AlexD I got it, it will just overflow, and the condition is always false cause the sum is still int in the valid range (irrespective of the overflow).

Comment: @Wintermute Yes, sure. I meant that even on platforms which allow overflows (and mostly they do), the result is still not useful.

Comment: @AlexD Oh, I see. Yes, you're right. Mind you, it is possible to test whether an addition will overflow without triggering the overflow, but then you'd still have the problem of swapping the numbers without addition. And it's really unlikely that the result of all this work would be faster than simply swapping in a triangle.

Comment: @Wintermute Yep, and I guess we can even end up (especially if we inline the function) with something like [`xchg`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_328.html).